# Uso de js y c# en unity. ¿Igual rendimiento?

Tags: javascript, c#, unity3d, unity2d

Estoy comenzando con unity . Y veo que se pueden usar c# y js para programar. Mi pregunta es si tanto c# como js tendrian el mismo rendimiento. Y si js puede hacer todas las funciones que puede hacer c#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unity utiliza UnityScript, un lenguaje con sintaxis similar a Javacript. Lamentablemente se lo suele llamar javascript (aunque no lo es).

Los tres lenguajes sobre los cuales es posible programar en Unity, es decir, C#, UnityScript y Boo compilan a CIL (Common Intermediate Language). Por lo que el rendimiento dependerá de como está implementado cada compilador.

En concreto sobre el rendimiento en sí, el concenso es que son similares, aunque es un poco mejor en C# (es decir la diferencia no es significativa).

Adicionalmente, el rendimiento no suele estar entre los principales motivos por lo que se aconseja utilizar C# por sobre UnityScript. Los motivos suelen ser:

1. UnityScript no es Javascript (saber Javascript otorga una ventaja despreciable)
2. Recursos (la mayoría de los assets de Unity están programados en C#)
3. Madurez, soporte y evolución de C#

Links a modo de referencias (en inglés):

*[1]: http://biggshark.com/why-using-c-with-unity-is-better-than-boo-and-js-for-your-next-mobile-game/
*[2]: http://dentedpixel.com/developer-diary/c-vs-unityscript-which-is-faster/

Comment: Discrepo con lo que dices, pues UnityScript era utilizado en versiones anteriores, JavaScript como tal sí es utilizado. Aqui unos links de referencia: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-JavaScript-and-UnityScript - 
 http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/index.html?_ga=1.178616292.1798511290.1472246433 - http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/UnityScript_versus_JavaScript

Comment: @fredyfx Leyendo la documentación no interpreto que ahora Unity soporte Javascript (EMACScript) :  "Unity supports two programming languages natively:   C# (...) UnityScript (...)". [CreatingAndUsingScripts -Manual Unity 5.4](http://docs.unity3d.com/540/Documentation/Manual/CreatingAndUsingScripts.html).
Del último link de tu comentario, el de UnityScript vs Javascript, puede leerse que el término UnityScript y Javascript se usan como si fueran lo mismo, pero no lo son.

Comment: interesante, toda una confusion, en los eventos que hacen sobre Unity3D mencionan que se puede usar JavaScript, inclusive en su misma documentación marea la terminología, gracias por la aclaracion :D

Answer (score 1):

Nop, el rendimiento es mayor en C# dado que es un lenguaje compilado y JavaScript interpretado. Sí, ambos lenguajes de programación en Unity3D tienen básicamente lo mismo, revisa la documentación.

Te recomiendo llevar unas clases en:

**Microsoft Virtual Academy - Curso para Desarrollo de Videojuegos con Unity3D**

> https://mva.microsoft.com/training-topics/game-development#!jobf=Developer&lang=1034